# What's the difference between game-based and simulation-based security?

Tags: protocol-design, provable-security, protocol-analysis, probabilistic-encryption

What's the difference between game-based and simulation-based security? When we use the simulation-based, how to construct the simulator based on the adversary?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://bristolcrypto.blogspot.com/2015/05/52-things-number-32-difference-between.html